# Why do i get different decimal points?

Tags: c#, decimal

I created a structure which contains several fields.
In that structure I have a property which calls a method which then creates a string out of those number for logging purposes.
When I use the property in the structure I get different decimal points Vs when I directly call the actual method which creates the log-string!
Suppose I have 9990M, if I use the structure it is 9990.0000 and when I call the method directly it prints 9990.00

This is my Method :

```
private static string CreateLog(
    long userId, decimal amount,
    long transactionID, decimal totalCash)
{


    Values = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}",
                            amount,
                            userId,
                            transactionId,
                            totalCash);
    return Values;
}
```

And my structure looks like this:

```
public struct AccountStruct
        {
            public long USER_ID;
            public decimal AMOUNT;
            public long TRANSACTION_ID;
            public decimal CURRENT_CASH;
            string ValuesToBeLoged
            {
                get
                {
                   return CreateLog(this);
                }
            }

        }
```

And CreateLog looks like this (calls the former method)

```
private static string CreateLog(AccountStruct accinfo)
        {
            return CreateLog(  accinfo.USER_ID,
                               accinfo.AMOUNT,
                               accinfo.TRANSACTION_ID,
                               accinfo.CURRENT_CASH);
        }
```

Why is it like this ? whats the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably some sort of internal normalization is going on. If you care about such matters, you need to specify how many decimal places you want in the ToString or String.Format method.

Look up Decimal.ToString(String) for your options. Usually I use the "Nx" where x is the number of decimal places.

Comment: I used Fx instead of Nx since i didnt want the separator . Thanks again , but i would like to know what exactly was it that caused such a difference

Comment: Internally, your decimal value could be stored as 9990 x 10^0 or 999 x 10^1 or 99900 x 10^-1. You would have to read the spec and examine the raw memory in order to figure out exactly when it is being transformed from one version to another. (Or it could be something else entirely.)

Comment: Thanks alot, I'll have a look at it